# Identifying crash with hs_err_pid*.log and gdb

Tags: gdb

**Update Sept. 12, 2011**

I was able to get the core file and immediately dissabled the instruction that crashed. As per advice I tracked the value of r28 (by the way, no registry entry was log to hs_err_pid*.log) and check where did the value come from (see below w/ <---). However, I was not able to determine the value of r32.

Could the reason for the miss-alignment is that r28 is a 8-byte integer loaded to a 4-byte integer r31?

```
;;;  1053               if( Transfer( len ) == FALSE ) {
0xc00000000c0c55c0:2 <TFM::PrintTrace(..)+0x32>:        adds         r44=0x480,r32;;  <---
0xc00000000c0c55d0:0 <TFM::PrintTrace(..)+0x40>:        ld8          r43=[ret2]
0xc00000000c0c55d0:1 <TFM::PrintTrace(..)+0x41>:  (p6)  st4          [r35]=ret3
0xc00000000c0c55d0:2 <TFM::PrintTrace(..)+0x42>:        adds         r48=28,r33
0xc00000000c0c55e0:0 <TFM::PrintTrace(..)+0x50>:        mov          ret0=0;;
0xc00000000c0c55e0:1 <TFM::PrintTrace(..)+0x51>:        ld8.c.clr    r62=[r45]
0xc00000000c0c55e0:2 <TFM::PrintTrace(..)+0x52>:        cmp.eq.unc   p6,p1=r0,r62
;;;  1056                       throw MutexLock ;
0xc00000000c0c55f0:0 <TFM::PrintTrace(..)+0x60>:        nop.m        0x0
0xc00000000c0c55f0:1 <TFM::PrintTrace(..)+0x61>:        nop.m        0x0
0xc00000000c0c55f0:2 <TFM::PrintTrace(..)+0x62>:  (p6)  br.cond.dpnt.many _NZ10TFM07PrintTraceEPi+0x800;;
;;;  1057               }
0xc00000000c0c5600:0 <TFM::PrintTrace(..)+0x70>:        adds         r41=0x488,r32
0xc00000000c0c5600:1 <TFM::PrintTrace(..)+0x71>:        adds         r40=0x490,r32
0xc00000000c0c5600:2 <TFM::PrintTrace(..)+0x72>:       br.call.dptk.many rp=0xc00000000c080620;;
;;;  1060               dwDataLen = len ;
0xc00000000c0c5610:0 <TFM::PrintTrace(..)+0x80>:        ld8          r16=[r44]    <---
0xc00000000c0c5610:1 <TFM::PrintTrace(..)+0x81>:        mov          gp=r36
0xc00000000c0c5610:2 <TFM::PrintTrace(..)+0x82>:  (p1)  mov          r62=8;;
0xc00000000c0c5620:0 <TFM::PrintTrace(..)+0x90>:        cmp.eq.unc   p6=r0,r16
0xc00000000c0c5620:1 <TFM::PrintTrace(..)+0x91>:        nop.m        0x0
0xc00000000c0c5620:2 <TFM::PrintTrace(..)+0x92>:  (p6)  br.cond.dpnt.many _NZ10TFM07PrintTraceEPi+0xda0;;
0xc00000000c0c5630:0 <TFM::PrintTrace(..)+0xa0>:        adds         r21=16,r16   <---
0xc00000000c0c5630:1 <TFM::PrintTrace(..)+0xa1>:  (p1)  mov          r62=8;;
0xc00000000c0c5630:2 <TFM::PrintTrace(..)+0xa2>:        nop.i        0x0
0xc00000000c0c5640:0 <TFM::PrintTrace(..)+0xb0>:        ld8          r42=[r21];;  <---
0xc00000000c0c5640:1 <TFM::PrintTrace(..)+0xb1>:        cmp.eq.unc   p6=r0,r42
0xc00000000c0c5640:2 <TFM::PrintTrace(..)+0xb2>:        nop.i        0x0
0xc00000000c0c5650:0 <TFM::PrintTrace(..)+0xc0>:        nop.m        0x0
0xc00000000c0c5650:1 <TFM::PrintTrace(..)+0xc1>:        mov          r47=5
0xc00000000c0c5650:2 <TFM::PrintTrace(..)+0xc2>:  (p6)  br.cond.dpnt.many _NZ10TFM07PrintTraceEPi+0xdf0;;
0xc00000000c0c5660:0 <TFM::PrintTrace(..)+0xd0>:        ld4.a        r27=[r48]
;;;  1064                       if( dwDataLen <= dwViewLen ) {
0xc00000000c0c5660:1 <TFM::PrintTrace(..)+0xd1>:        adds         r28=28,r42   <--
0xc00000000c0c5660:2 <TFM::PrintTrace(..)+0xd2>:        cmp.ne.unc   p6=r0,r46;;
0xc00000000c0c5670:0 <TFM::PrintTrace(..)+0xe0>:        ld4.sa       r26=[r28],
0xc00000000c0c5670:1 <TFM::PrintTrace(..)+0xe1>:  (p6)  ld4          r31=[r28]    <-- instruction that crashed
```

Let me know if register values are needed. I think I can acquire the register value using info reg command of gdb.
This is the result of info registers (I excluded values of prXXX and brXXX), I don't have any idea how to map these to the disassembled instruction above.

```
  gr1: 0x9fffffffbf716588
  gr2: 0x9fffffff5f667c00
  gr3: 0x9fffffff5f667c00
  gr4: 0x6000000000e0b000
  gr5: 0x9fffffff8adfe2e0
  gr6: 0x9fffffff8ada9000
  gr7: 0x9fffffff8ad7a000
  gr8:                0x1
  gr9: 0x9fffffff8adfd0f0
 gr10:                  0
 gr11: 0xc000000000000690
 gr12: 0x9fffffff8adfd140
 gr13: 0x6000000001681510
 gr14: 0x9fffffffbf7d8e98
 gr15:               0x1a
 gr16: 0x60000000044dac60
 gr17:               0x1f
 gr18:                  0
 gr19: 0x9fffffff8ad023f0
 gr20: 0x9fffffff8adfd0e0
 gr21: 0x60000000044dac70
 gr22: 0x9fffffff5f668000
 gr23:                0xd
 gr24:                0x1
 gr25: 0xc0000000004341f0
 gr26:                NaT
 gr27:               0x63
 gr28: 0xc00000000c5f801c
 gr29: 0xc00000000029db20
 gr30: 0xc00000000029db20
 gr31:              0x288
 gr32: 0x60000000044796d0
 gr33: 0x6000000001a78910
 gr34:               0x7e
 gr35: 0x6000000001d03a90
 gr36: 0x9fffffffbf716588
 gr37: 0xc000000000000c9d
 gr38: 0xc00000000c0c4f70
 gr39:                0x9
 gr40: 0x6000000004479b60
 gr41: 0x6000000004479b58
 gr42: 0xc00000000c5f8000
 gr43: 0x9fffffffbf7144e0
 gr44: 0x6000000004479b50
 gr45: 0x6000000004479b68
 gr46: 0x6000000001d03a90
 gr47:                0x5
 gr48: 0x6000000001a7892c
 gr49: 0x9fffffff8adfe110
 gr50: 0xc000000000000491
 gr51: 0xc00000000c0c5520
 gr52: 0xc00000000c07dd10
 gr53: 0x9fffffff8adfe120
 gr54: 0x9fffffff8adfe0a0
 gr55: 0xc00000000000058e
 gr56: 0xc00000000042be40
 gr57:               0x39
 gr58:                0x3
 gr59:               0x33
 gr60:                  0
 gr61: 0x9fffffffbf7d2598
 gr62:                0x8
 gr63: 0x9fffffffbf716588
 gr64: 0xc000000000000f22
 gr65: 0xc00000000c0c5610
```

---

This is an update to my previous post. Since I was furnished a copy
of the core file, I used gdb to examine the core file and executed
the following command:

1) bt

2) frame n <- the frame where the abort occurred

3) disas

And here are the results.

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0xc0000000001e5350:0 in _lwp_kill+0x30 ()
   from /usr/lib/hpux64/libpthread.so.1
#1  0xc00000000014c7b0:0 in pthread_kill+0x9d0 ()
   from /usr/lib/hpux64/libpthread.so.1
#2  0xc0000000002e4080:0 in raise+0xe0 () from /usr/lib/hpux64/libc.so.1
#3  0xc0000000003f47f0:0 in abort+0x170 () from /usr/lib/hpux64/libc.so.1
#4  0xc00000000e65e0d0:0 in os::abort ()
    at /CLO/Components/JAVA_HOTSPOT/Src/src/os/hp-ux/vm/os_hp-ux.cpp:2033
#5  0xc00000000eb473e0:0 in VMError::report_and_die ()
    at /CLO/Components/JAVA_HOTSPOT/Src/src/share/vm/utilities/vmError.cpp:1008
#6  0xc00000000e66fc90:0 in os::Hpux::JVM_handle_hpux_signal ()
    at /CLO/Components/JAVA_HOTSPOT/Src/src/os_cpu/hp-ux_ia64/vm/os_hp-ux_ia64.cpp:1051
#7  <signal handler called>
#8  0xc00000000c0c5670:1 in TFMTrace::PrintTrace () at tfmtrace.cpp:1064
#9  0xc00000000c0c4f70:0 in FMLogger::WriteLog () at fmlogger.cpp:90
...

(gdb) frame 8
#8  0xc00000000c0c5670:1 in TFMTrace::PrintTrace () at tfmtrace.cpp:1064
1064                            if( dwDataLen <= dwViewLen ) {
Current language:  auto; currently c++

(gdb) disas $pc-16*4 $pc+16*4
...
0xc00000000c0c5660:0 <TFMTrace::PrintTrace(...)+0xd0> :       ld4.a        r27=[r48]        MII,
;;;  1064               if( dwDataLen <= dwViewLen ) {
0xc00000000c0c5660:1 <TFMTrace::PrintTrace(...)+0xd1> :       adds         r28=28,r42
0xc00000000c0c5660:2 <TFMTrace::PrintTrace(...)+0xd2> :        cmp.ne.unc   p6=r0,r46;;
0xc00000000c0c5670:0 <TFMTrace::PrintTrace(...)+0xe0> :        ld4.sa      r26=[r28]        MMI,
0xc00000000c0c5670:1 <TFMTrace::PrintTrace(...)+0xe1> :  (p6)  ld4         r31=[r28]
0xc00000000c0c5670:2 <TFMTrace::PrintTrace(...)+0xe2> :       adds         r46=24,r42;;
0xc00000000c0c5680:0 <TFMTrace::PrintTrace(...)+0xf0> :  (p6)  st4       [r35]=r31         MI,I
0xc00000000c0c5680:1 <TFMTrace::PrintTrace(...)+0xf1> :       adds         r59=36,r42;;
0xc00000000c0c5680:2 <TFMTrace::PrintTrace(...)+0xf2> :        nop.i           0x0
0xc00000000c0c5690:0 <TFMTrace::PrintTrace(...)+0x100>:        ld4.c.clr   r27=[r48]        MIB,
;;;  1066               dwLen = dwTrcLen ;
0xc00000000c0c5690:1 <TFMTrace::PrintTrace(...)+0x101>:       cmp4.eq.unc  p6,p8=99,r27
0xc00000000c0c5690:2 <TFMTrace::PrintTrace(...)+0x102>:        nop.b           0x0;;
0xc00000000c0c56a0:0 <TFMTrace::PrintTrace(...)+0x110>:  (p8)  ld4.c.clr   r26=[r28]        MMI
;;;  1067               }
0xc00000000c0c56a0:1 <TFMTrace::PrintTrace(...)+0x111>:  (p6)  st4       [r48]=r47
0xc00000000c0c56a0:2 <TFMTrace::PrintTrace(...)+0x112>:       cmp4.geu.unc  p7=r26,r27
End of assemb
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "normal" crash in native code causes a report like this:

```
C  [libc.so.6+0x88368]  strstr+0x64a
```

Note small offset from the function (`strstr` in this case) to the crash point.

In your case, JVM decided that the address `oxc00000000f675671` is inside `libtracejni.so`, but the closest function it could find is *very* far from the crash point (0x5065eff9 == 1.2 GB away).

Is your library really that big?

If it really is that big, chances are you have stripped it, and so the symbol `_NZ10TFM07PrintTraceEPi` doesn't actually have anything to do with the problem (which is in the code that is 1.2GB away).

You need to find out what code was really at address `oxc00000000f675671` at the time of the crash. Usually `hs_err_pid*.log` contains a list of load addresses for all the shared libraries. Find the load address of `libtracejni.so`, subtract it from `pc`. That should give you an address similar to `0x400...675671` which you should be able to lookup in your unstripped version of `libtracejni.so`.

Also note that crash address ends with ASCII `"C8G"`, which may or may not be a coincidence.

Update 2011/08/05.

Now you know which instruction crashed:

```
0x4000000000099670:1 <TFMTrace::PrintTrace(...)+0xe1>: (p6) ld4         r31=[r28]
```

This is a load of 4-byte integer from memory pointed by `r28`.

The next questions are: what is the value of `r28` at crash point (should be logged in hs_err*.log), and also where did it come from (complete disassembly of `TFM::PrintTrace` will tell you that).

Comment: See follow-up on original post. The size of the library is **2.1MB**.